# main thread's request pending after service worker start

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have service worker installation in the 'load' event fire. The thing is I load main.js file in my html and that file contains ajax request for the local json file.

Service worker's install event makes requests and caches for assets. The issue is that the ajax request that main.js makes after it gets downloaded says `pending` in network tab and starts actually downloading after all the service worker's cache's addAll finishes.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing precaching in the install event of service worker? 
If yes try wrapping it in [waitUntil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ExtendableEvent/waitUntil).

It will make sure that your service worker is not being activated until the caching is complete.

The problem could be that fetch event listener of your service worker starts to look for assets in cache, before the cache is there.